# I am tying to create .exe for my django I used python freeze_script.py build but I'm getting error

Tags: django, exe

```
# freeze_script.py

import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# Manually configure Django settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DVE.settings')  # Replace 'your_project_name.settings' with your actual settings module
application = get_wsgi_application()
# Your Django project name (replace 'your_project_name' with your actual project name)
project_name = 'DVE'

base = None

if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [
    Executable("manage.py", base=base)
]

# Call the 'migrate' command before freezing
call_command("migrate")

# Freeze the application
build_options = {
    'packages': ['DVE','TOOL', 'django', 'gunicorn'],
    'includes': ['django.template.backends', 'django.templatetags.i18n'],
}


setup(
    name="TOOL",
    version="1.0",
    description="TOOL",
    options={"build_exe": build_options},
    executables=executables
)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

"C:\\Users\\AAMOLGHA\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwa reFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-p ackages\\Python310\\site-packages\\cx_Freeze\\initscripts_start up\_.py", line 124, in run

File module_init.run(name + "main\_")

File "C:\\Users\\AAMOLGHA\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwa reFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-p ackages\\Python310\\site-packages\\cx_Freeze\\initscripts\\consol e.py", line 16, in run

exec(code, module_main.dict\_) File "manage.py", line 22, in \<module\>

File "manage.py", line 18, in main

File "C:\\Users\\AAMOLGHA\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwa reFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-p ackages\\Python310\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\\ _init_\_.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()

File "C:\\Users\\AAMOLGHA\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwa reFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-p ackages\\Python310\\site-packages\\django\\core\\management\\ _init_\_.py", line 424, in execute

sys.stdout.write(self.main_help_text() + "\\n")

AttributeError: "NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
this is the error `your text`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where is your ```manage.py``` script?